# My while programme is getting overflowed? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: c++, loops

So the q is input 10 numbers and print the largest one using do while loop in c++. 
My programme was -

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>

void main()
{  
  clrscr();
  int i= 0, max, x;
  while ( i<10) 

    cout<<"enter a no"; 
    cin>>x;

  if (max==x) 
    i++;
  getch();
}
```

I'm a beginner so pls be specific. 
I want to print the highest number. What can I do for that?

Comment: I formatted your code better, but it is erroneous and won't even compile. Please submit the actual code you're using and the exact error you're getting with it.

Comment: It was supposed to be int i=0

Comment: there is and edit link under where it says [tag:loops].  You can also click this [edit] link.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, your code doesn't compile.

The error in your logic is that you prompt the user for input while `i` is less than ten, but you never change `i` - hence `i` will always be less than ten. Start from there.

Edit: with your new code:

```
while ( i<10)
  cout<<"enter a no";
```

`i` is still always less than ten, and, without brackets, the while loop will execute the row beneath it while `i` is less than ten. What you're doing is printing "enter a no" over and over again until the program stops.

Answer (score 0):

Did you copy someone else's code and leave out some bits?

The key to your problem is

```
if (max==x) 
    i++;
```

You don't want the i++ to be conditional on that `if`.

It is also the wrong `if` and you didn't show the declaration of `max`.  So the code you tested must be different from what you posted.  But the specific issue you asked about is from having `i++` conditional when it should be unconditional.

You wanted something such as

```
if (max<x)
{
    max=x;
}
i++;
```

Comment: The programme is still getting overflowed. Basically, I want the user to input 10 numbers. But it's accepted more than 10.

Answer (score 0):

First of all You're using a normal while loop, not a do while.

```
using namespace std;

int main() //main should return an int
{
    //decleare each variable
    int i = 0; 
    int x;
    int max;

    while (i < 10)
    {
        cout << "enter a no";
        cin >> x;
        if (i == 0 || x > max) 
            max = x;
        i++; //increment i in the loop
    }
    cout << max << endl;

    getchar();
    return 0; //return 0 if everything's ok
}
```

If You don't increment i in the loop or include a break statement, You have an infinite loop.

Comment: Why have we given the condition i==0 || x>max

Comment: if we've read the first number max is equals to it, cause we've only read one number. After that if the number we read is higher then the current max, change the max to be the new number.

Comment: If I remove the condition i==0 will it still work the same?

Comment: @Anon no, because max won't be initialized, so we can't compare it with other numbers